# how to connect to a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How do I connect to a MySQL database in PHP?

- Database name: `NewDB1`
- Username : `Mark`
- Password : `secret`

I have googled a few solutions, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Try to google it `php mysql database connection example`

Comment: Please show us those few solutions you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Mark";
$password = "secret";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) -

```
<?php

// turn on error reporting and display
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// define the user
define('USER', 'Mark');
define('PASS', 'secret');

// establish database connection
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NewDB1', USER, PASS);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // make sure to turn on error reporting
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); // show any error messages.
    $errorCode = $e->getCode();
}
?>
```

This comes from a more [detailed tutorial](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html) on how to understand and simplify PDO.